# Power-BI Slicer visualization

Tags: powerbi

In Power-BI is there any way to show only Column names instead of column values in Slicer visualization?

for example- suppose I have columns like country, site, siteID then in Slicer I don't want to show name of countries or name of sites instead I want to show column names like country, site, siteID in Slicer visualization.

Comment: This is not quite how PowerBI slicers work. Could you explain what you want to achieve? What you want your report to do?

Answer (score 0):

A slicer is a visual representation of a filter. If I use "month" as Slicer, then I decide to letzt the user filter "by month". I I would have the possibility to add column names of a kalender table, like "Date", "Weekday", "Month" would you like happen if the user takes "Date"?

Important are the values and the relationsships betweens the tables for filtering not the metainformation of columns or tables.